# Formatting json file in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, formatting

```
counter={"a":1,"b":2}
With open('egg.json' , 'w') as json_file:
   json.dump(counter, json_file)
```

So when I review my json file, it shows this:
{a:1 , b:2}
But I need it to be something like this:

> [ [a:1],  [b:2] ]

I've already tried adding

```
json.dump(counter, json_file, separator (' [  ', ' ] ')
```

But nothing will do the trick...
Is there a way to format the json file like the way you can format a CSV file?
I'd really like to know..... Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to do this? A dict is formatted with {} ... do you know of [xy-Problems](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: If you produce invalid json you make it very difficult for the consumer - think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[a:1], [b:2]` isn't valid json, so using the `json` module won't help you here.

If for some reason you want a formatted string output, you could instead do the following (don't call the file `egg.json` since it won't be valid json!):

```
counter = {'a':1, 'b':2}
output = []
for k, v in sorted(counter.items()):
  output.append('[{}:{}]'.format(k, v))
with open('egg.txt', 'w') as txt_f:
    txt_f.write(', '.join(output))
```